# Make or Have being Causative Verbs

Tags: word-choice, difference, causatives

When "Have and Make" are used as Causatives, I get confused because they seem the same in some sentences. Are there any difference between them in these sentences:

> The teacher *has* the students do the essay

> The teacher *makes* the students do the essay

> I *made* him cry

> I *had* him cry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the sentences certainly are different in meaning. It's the difference between forcing someone to do something ("to make" them do it) and requesting that they do it ("to have" them do it). The verb "to make" is very strong—to "have" someone do something is more like a request. Say I'm the boss at an office and I'm giving a task to an employee. There's a big difference between saying:

> "Could I have you do this for me?"

and

> "Could I make you do this for me?"

With the latter pair of your example sentences, "I had him cry" is a very odd thing to say. It certainly doesn't mean "I made him cry"—it means something more like "I directed him to cry". Again, the difference between forcing someone to do something and requesting that they do it.